# Can SQLite output a packed integer?

Tags: perl, sqlite

Is there a way to have SQLite output an unsigned integer in a packed/binary format?

I'm looking to have SQLite produce the equivalent of the perl function "print pack('I', 1_234_567_890)" where every integer (less than 2^32) is output using exactly 4 bytes (well, on my linux box on intel hardware; I know this stuff varies by hardware and endian-ness.)

Is there some printf formatting magic that will get me what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big-endian, 32-bit value (`l>`):

```
char( (N >> 24) & 255, (N >> 16) & 255, (N >> 8) & 255, N & 255 )
```

Little-endian, 32-bit value (`l<`):

```
char( N & 255, (N >> 8) & 255, (N >> 16) & 255, (N >> 24) & 255 )
```

Comment: The little endian version worked for me.  Thank you!  
  
One note to other readers is that this appears only to work with more recent versions of SQLite.  The default version of SQLite in the Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) repository (version 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30) doesn't support hex literals.  The default version of SQLite in the Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) repository (version 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24) does support hex literals

Comment: They both work; they simply do different things, as mentioned. /// 0xFF is 255. Updated the answer.